# How can a Storyboard triggered on a ControlTemplate be targeted to a generated child of the ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, styles, storyboard

Setting the `Storyboard.TargetName` doesn't work here.  It throws `'targetButton' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'`.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="aTemplate"
                 TargetType="someType">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="targetButton ???"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="..." />
            <Button Opacity="0"
                    x:Name="targetButton" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```